# Push code from GitHub to (suppose) GoDaddy automatically

Tags: git, web-hosting, github

Not sure if this is the correct StackExchange site to post this question. Please guide me accordingly if otherwise.

Assume that I got the code from my programmers and I reviewed it and pushed it to GitHub. Now, is there a way to have it automatically pushed to the live site hosted at (suppose) GoDaddy?

Any suggestions are very much welcomed.

Comment: If you downvote, please have the courtsey to mention `why?`

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, however I'm pretty sure this is being downvoted because it's not really a problem / resolution scenario. You're asking us to do your research and find a product or a service fitting your needs. Which isn't what serverfault is for.

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really has nothing to do with system administration.  Also, I wanted to show krisFR a custom close reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just *pull* it from GitHub on your servers, e.g. with a cron job.